# Set Text's initial position for marquee tag

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

I am using up direction for scrolling the text in the marquee tag in html.Initially it starts from bottom and then continue scrolling. I want to set it's initial position from top of the marquee height.Is it possible to do that or can it be done by using javascript. Please help.

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">Your vertically scrolling text goes here</marquee>
<p><a  style="font-size:11px;color:#999;" href="http://www.html.am/html-codes/text/">HTML text code</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

set his direction to down & hight to 100%

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down" height="100%">Your vertically scrolling text goes here</marquee>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't read the question properly. The OP doesn't want the text to move down.